# Combine two assosiative array's if (id) value are the same

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

So I got two associative arrays containing key-value pairs. They share one key name, and I want to add one array to the other if the `"name"` values are equal.

So if you have these arrays:

```
$array1 = [name=>"Foo", 
           date=>array("2016-06-06", "2016-06-05", "2016-06-04"), 
           (some other key-value pairs)];
$array2 = [name=>"Foo", 
           date=>array("2016-06-06", "2016-06-05", "2016-06-04"), 
           download_count=>array(54,23,15),
           (some other key-value pairs)];
```

the result should be something like this:

```
$newArray = [name=>"Foo", 
             date=>array("2016-06-06", "2016-06-05", "2016-06-04"),
             (the other key-value pairs from $array1),
             app=>array(
                  name=>"Foo", 
                  date=>array("2016-06-06", "2016-06-05", "2016-06-04"), 
                  download_count=>array(54,23,15),
                  (the other key-value pairs from $array2))]
```

Right now I try to loop through both of the array's to see where the names of both array's at index `$i,$j` are the same, and if they are combine the two.

Here is the code I use for that

```
foreach($array1 as $foo){
        foreach($array2 as $bar){
            if($foo["name"] == $bar["name"]){
                $foo["app"] = $bar;
            }
        }
    }
```

alternatively I tried with just regular `for` loops like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
        for($j = 0; $j < count($array2); $i++){
            if($array1[$i]["name"] == $array2[$j]["name"]){
                $array1[$i]["app"] = $array2[$j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result from the first example is just `$array1` (unchanged), and the result form the alternative example is an infinite loop.

Could someone help figure out how to get the desirable result?

**Edit**

Got it working, was just a beginners error in this case both for loops increased $i by one instead of the first loop adding one to $i and the other adding ine to $j

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer for future readers

Comment: It wasn't that much of a solution, just a stupid error on my side. But I'll keep it in mind! ;)